# Segue from callout in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, segue

Hi I have a mapView that has annotations pop up, I want to be able to segue when the annotation callout button is clicked. I have some problems though when I do it. I have a few questions
1) Do I have to embed the mapViewController in a navigation Controller? If yes, my annotations do not show up when I do, how come?
2) does prepareforsegue get called from performSegueWithIdentifier?
3) when u send self, in this case what would self be?
Thanks

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Present Photo" sender:self];
    }
```

Realized the problem it occurs here, I used to get a map controller from the id detail but now I think its a navigation controller, how do I get reference to the map controller now?

```
-(void) updateSplitViewDetail{
// ERROR OCCURS HERE!!! No longer map controller since I embed in navigation controller
id detail = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
if ([detail isKindOfClass:[MapViewController class]]) {
MapViewController *mapVC = (MapViewController*) detail;
mapVC.delegate = self;
mapVC.annotations = [self mapAnnotations];
}

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self updateSplitViewDetail]; //Error may be here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1)

Yes. If you want to perform a push segue, the source view controller (your map view controller) should be embedded in in navigation controller.

I'm not sure why your annotations/callouts aren't appearing in that case -- I've seen plenty of projects that work correctly that way. Perhaps your reference to the map view when you add the annotations isn't what you think it is? (And you're adding annotations to `nil` instead?) You'll need to provide more details for us to help. (Edit your question or post a new question since it's sort of a separate issue.)

### 2)

Yes. `prepareForSegue:sender:` is called after you call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

### 3)

The "sender" argument in these methods is entirely for your own use -- its sole reason for existence is to allow you to pass some context from the code that calls `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to the implementation of `prepareForSegue:sender:`. (Or in the case of segues automatically performed when the user taps some control, to allow your `prepareForSegue:sender:` implementation to know which control was tapped.)

So, pass whatever you want: `self` is fine, and so is `nil` if you're not making use of it. Or if it's useful for your `prepareForSegue:sender` implementation to know which callout was tapped, you might consider passing the annotation view's annotation as "sender" (say, so it can set up the destination view controller with appropriate info).

Comment: I am making an ipad app so I have a detail view Controller and on the detail side is my map and the root are some tables. Would I put two navigation controllers in the app one one the detail and one on the root?

Comment: When I embed the mapViewController in the navigation Controller viewforAnnotation doesnt get called, when I dont embed the mapviewcontroller then viewforannotation calls?

Comment: I found the problem Im just not sure how to fix it do U mind looking at the new code I added?